# Kaminari endless paging issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I am trying to use Kaminari + jQuery to do endless pagination / infinite scrolling.  I am trying to append the paginated results (rows) within a table.  Unfortunately, the results (row markup) appear above the table.  Here's my existing setup:

events_controller.rb

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @events = Event.all
    respond_with(@events)
  end

end
```

events/index.html.erb

```
<div id="events-container">

  <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      ...
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% if @events.blank? %>
        <tr><td> No events yet</td></tr>
      <% else %>
        <div id="events">
          <%= render @events %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <nav class="pagination-container">
    <%= paginate @events %>
  </nav>​

</div>​
```

events/index.js.erb

```
$('#events').append('<%= j render(@events) %>');

<% if (@events.current_page < @events.num_pages) %>
    $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j paginate(@events) %>');
<% else %>
    $('.pagination-container').remove();
<% end %>
```

events/_event.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td><%= event.time %></td>
  ...
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><%= event.location %></td>
  ...
</tr>
```

events_endless_paging.js

```
jQuery(function() {
  var isScrolledIntoView;
  isScrolledIntoView = function(elem) {
    var docViewBottom, docViewTop, elemBottom, elemTop;
    docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return (elemTop >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom);
  };

  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var url;
      url = $('.pagination .next a').attr('href');
      if (url && isScrolledIntoView('.pagination')) {
        $('.pagination').text('Fetching more...');

        var script = $.getScript(url);
        return script;
      }
    });

    return $(window).scroll();
  }
});
```

Everything seems to be wired properly, but what ends up happening is that table rows are inserted between #event-container div and the table.  So row styles are all wonky because the tags aren't being properly inserted within the context of a table.  I have the feeling that I need to insert table markup within the js response, but am not sure.

Comment: Does changing `$('#events').append('<%= j render(@events) %>');` to `$('#events > tbody:last').append('<%= j render(@events) %>');` yield any results? Untested, hence comment.

Comment: Good thought.  Unfortunately, the events weren't displayed anywhere.  Tried both append and prepend.  Going to tinker with your suggested approach some more, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think having a div inside the table body is valid.

If you remove the div and append the new rows to the tbody directly you should have more success.

```
<tbody>
  <% if @events.blank? %>
    <tr><td> No events yet</td></tr>
  <% else %>
    <%= render @events %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Sweet.  This worked: $('#events-container tbody').append('<%= j render(@events) %>');

Comment: Glad it worked for you, that being the case, would you consider accepting my answer?